# kvm in ubuntu desktop

Tags: kvm-virtualization

It's possible install kvm in ubuntu desktop version, or it only could be installed in server version.

Forums always explain over server version, I'm wandering if desktop version could do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can be installed on the desktop no bother.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Ubuntu's documentation is very good and will guide you through installing it and setting it up. If you are working on a Ubuntu with a desktop environment then install this package to manage your virtual machines.

```
sudo apt-get install virt-manager
```

Bill

Comment: Went in no fuss

Comment: I just wanna add the note that for me, when I followed the KVM installation instructions on Elementary OS Luna, my desktop environment became messed up. So I just uninstalled the desktop environment and reinstalled it.